# robotframework-imaplibrary2 0.3.2 is not working in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, imap, imaplib

After installing new robotframework-imaplibrary2 0.3.2 and try to use I get an error, “ No keyword with name 'Open Mailbox' found.”

open mailbox  host=outlook.office365.com  user=****** password=*******

No keyword with name 'Open Mailbox' found.

Comment: Are you importing the library in your test? Does your test generate an error on the import?

Comment: As per Keyword Documentation I use Library name : ImapLibrary. This new library does not have new document. Actually it show old library document.

Comment: This Library work now. I use imaplibrary2 instead imaplibrary.